# Converting pandas.core.series.Series to dataframe with appropriate column values python

Tags: python, pandas

i'm running a function in which a variable is of pandas.core.series.Series type.

```
type of the series shown below.

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
product_id_y    1159730
count                 1
Name: 6159402, dtype: object
```

i want to convert this into a dataframe,such that, i get

```
product_id_y    count
1159730           1
```

i tried doing this:

```
series1 = series1.to_frame()
```

but getting wrong result

after converting to dataframe

```
              6159402
product_id_y  1159730
count               1
```

after doing reset index i'e `series1 = series1.reset_index()`

```
           index  6159402
 0  product_id_y  1159730
 1         count        1
```

is there anny other way to do this??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You was very close, first [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and then transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1159730, 1], index=['product_id_y','count'], name=6159402)
print (s)
product_id_y    1159730
count                 1
Name: 6159402, dtype: int64

df = s.to_frame().T
print (df)
         product_id_y  count
6159402       1159730      1
```

---

```
df = s.rename(None).to_frame().T
print (df)
   product_id_y  count
0       1159730      1
```

Another solution with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([s])
print (df)
         product_id_y  count
6159402       1159730      1
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([s.rename(None)])
print (df)
   product_id_y  count
0       1159730      1
```

Comment: if i have to remove the index from my final df should df.reset_index() work?

Comment: better `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: great! when i only did `df.reset_index()` it made another column called as index, now it is fine after i did `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I found better solution with `rename` `Series`, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Will','John','John','John','Alex'],
                   'Payment':  [15, 10, 10, 10, 15],
                   'Duration':    [30, 15, 15, 15, 20]})
```

You can print by converting the series/dataframe to string:

```
> print (df.to_string())
   Duration  Name  Payment
0        30  Will       15
1        15  John       10
2        15  John       10
3        15  John       10
4        20  Alex       15

> print (df.iloc[1].to_string())
Duration      15
Name        John
Payment       10
```